# How to import external jar into my project with vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am trying to add external jar into my project with vscode.

To manage the classpath with Eclipse, I right-click on my project and select Properties, Java Build Path | Libraries.

How to do this with vscode?

ms docs gives this tutorial.

[image]

I cannot find **LIBPROJ** in my vscode. Does that need some extension, if yes, what it is?

PS: I've already installed Java Extension Pack, [Spring Boot Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Pivotal.vscode-spring-boot), and [Spring Boot Dashboard](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-spring-boot-dashboard).

Comment: you could refer to [add external jar](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_adding-external-jar)

Answer (score 0):

With installing the "Java Extension Pack" also was installed the "Java Dependency Viewer".

So now you can add libraries by editing the .classpath file with custom entries of JARs that may be placed anywhere, for example a lib folder. The extensions will automatically load those libraries in the classpath and you should be able to run your code.

[image]